# Pass data from dynamicallyloadedcomponent back to parent page Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm wondering if there is any way to pass data back from a dynamically loaded component in Angular2. I pass the component data using

```
this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(...).then(component => {
  component.instance.variable = this.variable;
}
```

On completing the tasks inside the component, in my case a modal, can I pass data or variables back out in a similar manner? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `Observable` to the dynamically added component
(an `EventEmitter` might work as well but might break eventually. Then Angular2 team doesn't guarantee that an `EventEmitter` will keep behaving like an observable)

Then just subscribe to this observable

```
this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(...).then(component => {
  component.instance.variable = this.variable;
  component.instance.someObservable.subscribe(val => this.someVal = val);
}
```

`DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated and AFAIK was already removed in master.

See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)